# How to use "have an impact"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, prepositions, writing-style

I was wondering whether saying "have an impact" instead of "have an impact on" is idiomatically correct.

"He aspired to have an impact through education and hard work."

Comment: In that sentence, I think "make an impact" would sound more natural. See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23726/difference-in-meaning-between-create-make-have-impact).

Comment: It's the "on" bit I am wondering about.

Comment: Well **if** you're specifying the area of impact, then you should use "on", and *"having an impact on..."* is fine (though possibly less dramatic than "making...")

Comment: Does not specifying an area of impact create ambiguity?

Comment: "Have an impact" or "make an impact" without immediately specifying the area of said impact is not uncommon.  Generally, the context of the sentence should give some clue as to the area, but often the meaning is "have an impact on society" or something else just as vague.  Basically, it signifies a desire/tendency to be "socially relevant".

Comment: You may find "have an impact" without "on" in a debate. For example, "And of course it will have an impact. But ...".